# Nodejs S3 upload list[0]" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs, openpgp.js

I'm using openpgp.js to encrypt a s3 `getObject` stream. After the encryption I try to upload the encrypted stream using `s3.upload()` which results in the error:

> S3 upload list[0]" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array

The error only shows up if I use the option `armor: true` (which I want) in the encryption stream.
Here is the relevant extract from the code:

```
let encryptionStream = await openpgp.encrypt({        
        message: pgpMessage,
        publicKeys: publicKey,
        privateKeys: privateKey,
        streaming: 'node',        
        armor: true  
});

var uploadObjectAsync = async (s3Params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(s3Params, (err, data) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
});

await uploadObjectAsync({'Bucket': 'test-upload', 'Key': 'encrypted_file', 'Body': encryptionStream, });
```

I also took a look at this github issue but using `encryptionStream.setEncoding(null)` still results in the same error
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2081